# MySql: select total grouped by two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `transactions` like this: http://prntscr.com/aa5vg6
I want to select total amount group by `purpose` and `date` column. Such as: found 10 records for purpose 1, 21 records for purpose 2 and so on... in the date 2016-02-01, 2016-02-05 and so on... the result should be total sum of purpose and the purpose total should be grouped by date.

I tried this query, but it fails grouping the date while multiple purpose found in same date:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) totalAmount FROM `transactions` WHERE purpose IN(1,2,12) GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should group by date and purpose in that case:

```
SELECT
    DATE(`date`) date,
    `purpose`,
    COUNT(`purpose`) purposeCount,
    SUM(`amount`) totalAmount
FROM
    `transactions`
WHERE
    `purpose` IN (1, 2, 12)
GROUP BY
    DATE(`date`),
    `purpose`
ORDER BY
    DATE(`date`) DESC
```

Comment: It returns this: http://prntscr.com/aa64x9 where the date 2016-02-13, 2016-02-16 and 2016-02-18 should be grouped by, but it did not.

Comment: simply just get DATE from datetime column - see the update. you didn't mention that date is actually in datetime format.

Comment: Thanks, yes the issue was with the date format. It solved..!